# pclose with NULL parameter

Tags: c, linux

Which one should I choose:

1.`pclose` should not be attempted if `popen` has already failed, even though it's tolerant in handling `NULL` handle.

2.Passing whatever `popen` returns to `pclose`, just like it's ok to pass whatever `malloc` returns to `free`.

After I carefully read the manual(i.e.:`man pclose`), I can't find any evidence that `pclose` could handle `NULL` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't demand that `pclose` gracefully handle a `NULL` argument, you can't rely upon it.  Now, it may be that a particular libc implementation provides that guarantee but, if you want to maintain portability, you should only rely upon guaranteed behavior.